# Ruby, Net-SSH: connection closed by remote host

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

Issue where SSH session gets disconnected after less than 1 sec by remote when using ruby net-ssh. It happens very randomly.

```
/home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:89:in `next_packet': connection closed by remote host (Net::SSH::Disconnect)
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:183:in `block in poll_message'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `loop'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `poll_message'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:461:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:222:in `preprocess'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:206:in `process'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `block in loop'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from /home/user/ruby/cisco/ssh.rb:43:in `run'
    from /home/user/ruby/cisco/base.rb:48:in `run'
    from rssh.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Already tried specifying timeout settings and encryption algorithms.
Solution at https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/93 does not fix the issue

Comment: Remote host is in it's own right to close connections. Your code has to handle the case and simply reconnect. You can’t expect that remote server will serve your sessions forever.

Comment: Can you confirm it does not happen with plain `ssh` from bash?

Comment: - The connection never stays alive more then 10 sec as intended, but the remote disconnect happens right after connecting to the device (less then 1 sec connected) @mudasobwa

Comment: - When running it in plain SSH from bash, it does not have this problem @gmaliar

Comment: Are you are using plain auth or public/private keys?

Comment: @Lectral i am using plain auth

Comment: @metroid is this still an issue? Please include the code (the Net::SSH block) in the question body.

Comment: I'm now using Ruby 2.3 and net/ssh 4.1.0 gem and it still has the problem when i use plain auth to connect to an OpenSSH server on NetBSD 7.0
This is still a bug

Comment: humbly: what is the need to modify/edit this question now, are you going to answer the question? mr. @user2066657

Comment: ajay_speed:  I don't understand the confusion, as independently both answers are obvious.